# Is there an AWS Instance Uptime Calculator?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-rds, amazon-elb

Amazon publishes an SLA, but when designing a resilient multi availability zone and multi region system is it possible to calculate the overall uptime (as presented to the user)?

For example, what is the likely uptime for 3 EC2 instances using ELB in 3 different availability zones in the same region vs 4 EC2 instances in 2 different regions?

Then when we add RDS instances, Route 53, Cloudfront etc, what is the likely impact (positive and negative)?

Other factors, such as RDS failure switchover time, cloudfront caching, etc should ideally be part of the calculation input.

Or - is it better to just assume a number for a one region of 99.9x percent and two regions as 99.99x percent?

EDIT - I am trying to calculate likely downtime (for all/majority of users) of a "well designed web-facing AWS solution".  Ideally I would love something like the AWS pricing tool (or which takes pricing tool output) to calculate likely downtime either per month or over a year.  That way I can calculate costs and risks of different designs e.g. does the RDS really need multi-AZ at an extra $100+ per month.

Comment: Are you asking for theoretical uptime or actual historical uptime?

Comment: Theoretical uptime, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating theoretical uptime of a system is difficult because you would need to determine exactly what is meant by 'uptime'.

For example, if there was a network outage such that some of your users CAN access the system, but some CANNOT, would the whole system be deemed 'down'?

Also, there is a difference between:

- **SLAs** that offer some money back if a certain performance level is not met
- **Architectural design** that aims for a certain level of uptime (eg "Amazon S3 is designed to provide 99.999999999% durability of objects over a given year")
- **Actual performance** over a given period

Using multiple Availability Zones is a good design decision since **an outage affecting one AZ should not impact another AZ**. However, there are no published statements about AZ up-time. (Indeed, there has not been any historical outages of whole Availability Zones, but sometimes an individual service within one Availability Zone can be impacted by an issue.)

There should also be no need to use multiple Regions for achieving higher up-time, since Availability Zones are designed for this purpose. However, some organizations do choose to use multiple regions (eg when Hurricane Sandy threatened the US East-coast).

Most AWS services are designed to handle failure. For example, Amazon Route 53 has a ["100% Available" SLA](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/sla/) because it exists in 50+ locations around the world.

**Bottom line:** If you have designed a solution that uses at least two Availability Zones and takes into account failures (eg multi-AZ mode in Amazon RDS, storing data in Amazon S3 that automatically replicates between AZs), then you will have a Highly-Available architecture that should be able to handle most failures. Actually designing a system to be Highly Available is better than calculating theoretical percentages.

Comment: Thanks John - I (hopefully) edited the question to clarify a design goal of not overcooking the resilience and expense but achieving no more than "x" amount of downtime over a month or year.